# Zooming to mouse position using glOrtho

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, mouse

Currently I am using glOrtho to zoom and pan around a 2D graph I am rendering.

I have setup up the viewport to the standard width and height. Then I set the glOrtho so that my frustrum makes screen coordinates match world coordinates.

```
glViewport(0, 0, window_width,window_height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, window_width,window_height,0 , 100, -100);
```

When I do my zoom function in my mouse callback, I multiply the frustrum edges by a zoom factor....

```
glOrtho( 0 * zoomOut,
window_width * zoomOut,
window_height * zoomOut,
0 * zoomOut, 
100, -100);
```

My question is.... how do I zoom using mouse position as a centre?

I have tried this... (where mouseStoreX and mouseStoreY are the position stored at the first click)

```
glOrtho( (0 -mouseStoreX )* zoomOut + mouseStoreX,
(window_width - mouseStoreX) * zoomOut + mouseStoreX,
(window_height - mouseStoreY) * zoomOut + mouseStoreY,
(0 - mouseStoreY) * zoomOut + mouseStoreY, 
100, -100);
```

It seems to work but the frustrum jumps around when I do a new click. I think somewhere I'm not taking into account the zoomOut factor when doing the mouse position storing.

EDIT: here is my latest code which I am still struggling with...

```
void ZoomOrtho(){ //ON MOUSE CLICK.....

if (zooming == false){
keyStore.LMx = keyStore.Mx;   //store mouse pos for next comparison
keyStore.LMy = keyStore.My;
//get mouse pos
mouseStoreX = keyStore.Mx;//mouse pos at this moment
mouseStoreY = keyStore.My;

//get current projection matrices
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );
//flip Y for opengl reasons
winY = (float)viewport[3] - winY;
//get world mouse coordinate
gluUnProject( mouseStoreX, mouseStoreY , 0.0, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX_,&posY_, &posZ_);

// calc difference between mouse world pos and centre of 'camera'
dx = posX_ - FS.centerX;
dy = posY_ - FS.centerY;

}
//ON DRAG......
zooming = true;

//do mouse movement detection and increment zoomOut
//#################################################
int xDiff = keyStore.Mx - keyStore.LMx;  //mouse drag difference in screen space just  for incrementing zoom
int yDiff = keyStore.My - keyStore.LMy;  //

if (xDiff > 0 && (zoomFactor >= 0.5 ) )   {
zoomFactor -= zoomInc;
if  (zoomFactor < 0.5 ) {zoomFactor = 0.5;}
}
else if (xDiff < 0 && (zoomFactor <= 2.0 ))  {
zoomFactor += zoomInc;
if (zoomFactor > 2.0){zoomFactor = 2.0;}
}
//#################################################


//fill structure with clipping plane values. zooms ortho projection and keeps mouse pos anchored.
FS.left =  ((FS.centerX - dx - (window_width/2.0))*zoomFactor) +dx;
FS.right = ((FS.centerX -dx + (window_width/2.0))*zoomFactor)+dx ;
FS.bottom = ((FS.centerY -dy + (window_width/2.0))*zoomFactor)+dy;
FS.top =    ((FS.centerY -dy  - (window_width/2.0))*zoomFactor) +dy;

// store last mouse pos for next comparison.
keyStore.LMx = keyStore.Mx;
keyStore.LMy = keyStore.My;

}

void zoomRelease(){

cout << " releasing" << std::endl;
//set zoom to false so we know we are not draggin mouse anymore.
zooming = false;
keyStore.LMx = 0;
keyStore.LMy = 0;

// recenter by taking midpoint between new left and right clipping planes so dx has a reference point
FS.centreX = (FS.right-FS.left)/2.0;

}

void DrawGui(){

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(FS.left, FS.right,FS.bottom, FS.top, 1, -1);

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
//do drawing

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -lglut -lGL && ./main
#include <GL/glut.h>

double centerX = 0, centerY = 0;
double width = 0, height = 0;
void mouse( int button, int state, int mx, int my )
{
    // flip mouse y axis so up is +y
    my = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - my;

    // convert mouse coords to (-1/2,-1/2)-(1/2, 1/2) box
    double x = ( mx / (double)glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) ) - 0.5;
    double y = ( my / (double)glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) ) - 0.5;

    if( GLUT_UP == state )
    {
        double preX = ( x * width );
        double preY = ( y * height );

        double zoomFactor = 1.5;
        if( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON )
        {
            // zoom in
            width /= zoomFactor;
            height /= zoomFactor;
        }
        if( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON )
        {
            // zoom out
            width *= zoomFactor;
            height *= zoomFactor;
        }

        double postX = ( x * width );
        double postY = ( y * height );

        // recenter
        centerX += ( preX - postX );
        centerY += ( preY - postY );
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho
        (
        centerX - ( width / 2.0 ),
        centerX + ( width / 2.0 ),
        centerY - ( height / 2.0 ),
        centerY + ( height / 2.0 ),
        -1,
        1     
        );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 150, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( -150, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, -150 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );

    width = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    height = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );    

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your information is helpful but not exactly what I wanted. I am trying to zoom while dragging the mouse. I am now trying to unproject the screen coordinates to world coords and then recaculate the centre value when I release the mouse. The aim is to drag the mouse and the point underneath the mouse be the pivot.

Comment: I have this working now. I was before unprojecting mouse coordinates into world space, calcing offsets and recentering after mouse release but was still getting strange jumps that I couldn't track down. I think it was due to not concatenating transforms. This solution is a lot more straightforward. I did however add my own tweak which was to invert the zoomfactor (1/zoomfactor) if baseY was negative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you do the second click you're storing its value into mouseStoreXY. If so, this is causing the jumping. You were drawing with an offset of the old mouseStoreXY and you suddenly offset to the new one.

The solution will be to store the projection matrix inputs persistently and then modify them incrementally on each frame.

Comment: Yes I realise that now. I am trying to keep track of the offsets now but cant get it exact at the moment. Thanks your your help.

Comment: I have the same issue - what does this mean do it incrementally?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -lglut -lGL && ./main
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

void getMouseCoords( int mx, int my, double& x, double& y )
{
    // flip mouse y axis so up is +y
    my = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - my;

    // convert mouse coords to (-1/2,-1/2)-(1/2, 1/2) box
    x = ( mx / (double)glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) ) - 0.5;
    y = ( my / (double)glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) ) - 0.5;
}

int btn;
double baseX, baseY;
double baseWidth, baseHeight;

double centerX = 0, centerY = 0;
double width = 0, height = 0;
void mouse( int button, int state, int mx, int my )
{
    baseWidth = width;
    baseHeight = height;
    btn = button;
    getMouseCoords( mx, my, baseX, baseY );
}

void motion( int mx, int my )
{
    if( btn != GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON )
    {
        return;
    }

    double x, y;
    getMouseCoords( mx, my, x, y );

    double preX = ( baseX * width );
    double preY = ( baseY * height );

    double zoomFactor = exp( baseY - y );
    width = baseWidth * zoomFactor;
    height = baseHeight * zoomFactor;

    double postX = ( baseX * width );
    double postY = ( baseY * height );

    // recenter
    centerX += ( preX - postX );
    centerY += ( preY - postY );

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho
        (
        centerX - ( width / 2.0 ),
        centerX + ( width / 2.0 ),
        centerY - ( height / 2.0 ),
        centerY + ( height / 2.0 ),
        -1,
        1     
        );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 150, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 150 );
    glVertex2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex2i( -150, 0 );
    glVertex2i( 0, -150 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutMotionFunc( motion );

    width = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    height = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );    

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly the behaviour. Thank you so much. I should be able to get this working in my code. I had almost figured it out but you've made it very clear. I would buy you a pint good sir!

Comment: Actually I can't actually get this to work with panning. I've editied my code above to show what I was doing previously.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go a different route and simply use glTranslate and gluPerspective, you can acheive the same effect. The mouse event for the scroll wheel (using PyOpenGL) might look something like:

```
def MouseWheelScroll(self, event):
    """Called when the mouse's scroll wheel is scrolled up or down. This modifies the zoomFactor
    which renders the graphics closer or further away on the screen. It also translates the graphics
    slightly based on the position of the mouse. This creates an effect of zooming to the location
    of the mouse on the screen.
    """
    scrolledUp = event.GetWheelRotation() # Returns positive for up, negative for down
    self.x, self.y = event.GetPosition()

    viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
    width = viewport[2]
    height = viewport[3]
    centerX = width / 2.0
    centerY = height / 2.0

    # Make sure cursor is on the screen
    if ((self.x > 0 and self.x < width) and (self.y > 0 and self.y < height)):
        if (scrolledUp > 0):
            self.zoomFactor -= 2.0
            self.translation[0] -= (self.x - centerX)
            self.translation[1] += (self.y - centerY)
        else:
            self.zoomFactor += 2.0
            self.translation[0] += (self.x - centerX)
            self.translation[1] += (self.y - centerY)

        if (self.zoomFactor > 150.0):
            self.zoomFactor = 150.0
        elif (self.zoomFactor < 0.1):
            self.zoomFactor = 0.1

    self.Refresh(False)
```

You would then just need to translate the graphics, set up your perspective, and then render the scene.

```
# Translate graphics
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, (self.translation[1]/100.0) * (math.tan(self.cameraPosition[0]/self.cameraPosition[1])))
glTranslatef(0.0, (self.translation[0]/100.0) * (math.tan(self.cameraPosition[0]/self.cameraPosition[1])), 0.0)

# Set Perspective
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(self.zoomFactor, float(width)/float(height), self.nearPlane, self.farPlane)

# Render Scene
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
...Draw stuff here...
```